# Tricky view that displays only most current values plus any old ones that haven't been updated

Tags: sql, pivot, max

I have a table that gets updates of certain information, but not necessarily all information on a regular basis. I need a query that returns all the most recent fields, but doesn't return any duplicates. For example,

[image: Source Table View]

Here you can see that we got an updated closure date on 8/30 of 12/31 (used to be NULL). None of the other values I have got updated, but I still need to return all the values plus the new closure date.

Code to create Files table:

```
CREATE TABLE IntersectIOTest.[dbo].[Files_Dummy](
                [sysID] int,
                [ZipFileName] varchar (64),
                [TextFileName] varchar (64),
                [ImportBatchDate] date,
                [ImportFileDate] date,
                [ArchiveLocation] varchar (64),
                [ImportOutcome] varchar (16),
                [FileDescription] varchar (16),
                [ValuationDate] date,
                [FileSize] int
)

INSERT INTO IntersectIOTest.[dbo].[Files_Dummy]( 
            [sysID],
            [ZipFileName],
            [TextFileName],
            [ImportBatchDate],
            [ImportFileDate],
            [ArchiveLocation],
            [ImportOutcome],
            [FileDescription],
            [ValuationDate],
            [FileSize]
)

VALUES 
    (3040,'RT630D_40932_2019_05_25_0000017775.zip','RT630D_40932_2019_05_25_0000017775.txt','2019-05-25 05:00:23.000','2019-05-25 05:00:23.000','C:\File Storage\Archive','Successful','SpecialCoding','2019-05-25',NULL),
    (4783,'RT630D_40932_2019_08_31_0000017775.zip','RT630D_40932_2019_08_31_0000017775.txt','2019-08-31 02:00:29.000','2019-08-31 02:00:29.000','C:\File Storage\Archive','Successful','SpecialCoding','2019-08-31',NULL);
```

Here is the code I currently have:

```
WITH
FILES AS
(
SELECT      *
FROM        [dbo].[Files]
WHERE       ImportOutcome = 'Successful'
AND         FileDescription IN ('SpecialCoding')
),

SPCMAX AS
(
SELECT      *
FROM        (
            SELECT      MAX(FILES.ValuationDate) OVER (PARTITION BY [Claim-Number], Question /*addedd Question here*/) MAXVAL,
                        FILES.ValuationDate, FileID, [Claim-Number], [Question], [Response]
            FROM        [dbo].[SpecialCoding] SC
            INNER JOIN  FILES
            ON          SC.FileID = FILES.sysID
            WHERE       SC.Response IS NOT NULL -- Added this line here
            ) AS SC
PIVOT
            (
            MAX(Response)
            FOR Question IN ([Client Name], [Customer Number], [Record Only], [Reorting Source Indicator Description], [Estimated Claim Closure Date])
            ) AS PivotTable
WHERE       MAXVAL = ValuationDate
)

SELECT      ValuationDate, FileID, [Claim-Number], [Client Name], [Customer Number], [Record Only],
            [Reorting Source Indicator Description], [Estimated Claim Closure Date]
FROM        SPCMAX
```

My current script pivots the data and is returning two rows.

[Current Results (Updated 12/26)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVOTp.png)

What I need is this

[Needed view results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbaoX.png)

Thanks in advance for any help.

**12/18 Update - Here is the real table I'm working from**
**12/26 Update - Added code to create Files table and new current code**

[Results for one claim where we are getting NULL values in the view we are creating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7A0v.png)

Comment: Will there always be the same 5 questions for each event? If so, will all 5 always exist even if every other value in that row is `Null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 2019-12-18 DUE TO CHANGE IN REQUIREMENTS**

**UPDATE 2019-12-25 DUE TO UPDATED INFORMATION**

Please post your data in an easy to use way so people can help you easier. It's hard to help without knowing your data. I went ahead and did it for you so we could resolve this issue. You also need to clearly specify what data you currently have and exactly how you want it. You changed things several times, brought in new data elements, and some different logic so it made it challenging.

I was able to use to get a solution using `CASE` statements and the `PIVOT` function. The `PIVOT` table could probably be cleaned up a little, but both solutions get you the desired results.

**SQL Code to Create Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SpecialCoding](
             [Record-Type] varchar(2),
             [Client-Program] int,
             [Event-Number] varchar(16),
             [Claim-Number] varchar(16),
             [Line-Of-Business] varchar(2),
             [Question-Number] int,
             [CP-Seq-Number] int,
             [Question] varchar(64),
             [Response] varchar(64),
             [Date-Added] date,
             [Date-Updated] date,
             [Filler] varchar(2),
             [FileID] int,
             [sysID] int
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[SpecialCoding]( 
            [Record-Type],
            [Client-Program],
            [Event-Number],
            [Claim-Number],
            [Line-Of-Business],
            [Question-Number],
            [CP-Seq-Number],
            [Question],
            [Response],
            [Date-Added],
            [Date-Updated],
            [Filler],
            [FileID],
            [sysID]
)

VALUES 
       ('SC',29274,189008589,'189008589-001','WC',38,1,'Client Name','DALTON ENTERPRISES','20190524','20190524',NULL,3040,125045),
       ('SC',29274,189008589,'189008589-001','WC',2046,2,'Record Only','N','20190524','20190524',NULL,3040,125046),
       ('SC',29274,189008589,'189008589-001','WC',2558,3,'Customer Number',NULL,'20190524','20190524',NULL,3040,125047),
       ('SC',29274,189008589,'189008589-001','WC',2691,54,'Reporting Source Indicator Description','ELR','20190524','20190524',NULL,3040,125048),
       ('SC',29274,189008589,'189008589-001','WC',2842,55,'Estimated Claim Closure Date',NULL,'20190524','20190524',NULL,3040,125049),
       ('SC',29274,189008589,'189008589-001','WC',2842,55,'Estimated Claim Closure Date','2020-12-31','20190524','20190830',NULL,4783,138941);
```

**WINDOW FUNCTION WITH CASE SOLUTION**

```
WITH CTE AS (
             SELECT SC.*
               FROM [dbo].[SpecialCoding] SC
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Files_Dummy] as FILES
                    ON SC.[FileID] = FILES.[sysID]
                       AND FILES.[ImportOutcome] = 'Successful'
                       AND FILES.[FileDescription] IN ('SpecialCoding')),

      MAXDATE AS( 
             SELECT [Claim-Number],
                    MAX([Date-Updated]) AS MAX_DATE
               FROM CTE
              GROUP BY [Claim-Number]),

     FILENUMBER AS(
               SELECT CTE.[Claim-Number],
                      CTE.[FileID]
                 FROM CTE
                      INNER JOIN MAXDATE MD
                      ON CTE.[Claim-Number] = MD.[Claim-Number]
                         AND CTE.[Date-Updated] = MD.[MAX_DATE]),
       SUB AS (
         SELECT *
           FROM (
                 SELECT CTE.*,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Claim-Number], [Question-Number] ORDER BY [Date-Updated] DESC) AS ROWN
                   FROM CTE) SUB  
                  WHERE SUB.[ROWN] = 1)

SELECT sub.*, 
       MAXDATE.MAX_DATE AS "Valuation Date",
       FILENUMBER.[FileID] 
  FROM (
        SELECT CTE.[Claim-Number],
               MAX(CASE WHEN CTE.[Question-Number] = 38 THEN CTE.Response ELSE NULL END) AS [Client Name],
               MAX(CASE WHEN CTE.[Question-Number] = 2046 THEN CTE.Response ELSE NULL END) AS [Record Only],
               MAX(CASE WHEN CTE.[Question-Number] = 2558 THEN CTE.Response ELSE NULL END) AS [Customer Number],
               MAX(CASE WHEN CTE.[Question-Number] = 2691 THEN CTE.Response ELSE NULL END) AS [Reporting Source],
               MAX(CASE WHEN CTE.[Question-Number] = 2842 THEN CTE.Response ELSE NULL END) AS [Estimated Closure Date]
          FROM CTE
         GROUP BY CTE.[Claim-Number]) sub
        LEFT JOIN MAXDATE
        ON MAXDATE.[Claim-Number] = sub.[Claim-Number]
        LEFT JOIN FILENUMBER
        ON FILENUMBER.[Claim-Number] = sub.[Claim-Number];
```

**WINDOW FUNCTION WITH PIVOT SOLUTION**

```
WITH CTE AS (
             SELECT SC.*
               FROM [dbo].[SpecialCoding] SC
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Files_Dummy] as FILES
                    ON SC.[FileID] = FILES.[sysID]
                       AND FILES.[ImportOutcome] = 'Successful'
                       AND FILES.[FileDescription] IN ('SpecialCoding')),

      MAXDATE AS( 
             SELECT [Claim-Number],
                    MAX([Date-Updated]) AS MAX_DATE
               FROM CTE
              GROUP BY [Claim-Number]),

     FILENUMBER AS(
               SELECT CTE.[Claim-Number],
                      CTE.[FileID]
                 FROM CTE
                      INNER JOIN MAXDATE MD
                      ON CTE.[Claim-Number] = MD.[Claim-Number]
                         AND CTE.[Date-Updated] = MD.[MAX_DATE]),
       SUB AS (
         SELECT *
           FROM (
                 SELECT CTE.*,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Claim-Number], [Question-Number] ORDER BY [Date-Updated] DESC) AS ROWN
                   FROM CTE) SUB  
                  WHERE SUB.[ROWN] = 1),

PT AS (
        SELECT *
          FROM (
                SELECT CTE.[Claim-Number],
                       CTE.[Question-Number],
                       CTE.[Response]
                  FROM CTE
                 ) sub
         PIVOT (
           MAX([Response])
           FOR [Question-Number] IN ([38],[2046],[2558],[2691],[2842])) AS pivot_table)
         SELECT PT.[38] AS "Client Name",
                PT.[2046] AS "Record Only",
                PT.[2558] AS "Customer Number",
                PT.[2691] AS "Reporting Source Indicator Description",
                PT.[2842] AS "Estimated Claim Closure Date", 
                MAXDATE.[MAX_DATE] AS [Valuation Date], 
                FILENUMBER.[FileID]
           FROM PT
                LEFT JOIN MAXDATE
                ON MAXDATE.[Claim-Number] = PT.[Claim-Number]
                LEFT JOIN FILENUMBER
                ON FILENUMBER.[Claim-Number] = PT.[Claim-Number];
```

**CASE SOLUTION**

```
WITH FILES AS (
                SELECT *
                  FROM [dbo].[Files_Dummy]
                 WHERE ImportOutcome = 'Successful'
                  AND FileDescription IN ('SpecialCoding')),

     CTE AS (
             SELECT [Claim-Number],
                    [Question-Number],
                    MAX([Date-Updated]) AS MAX_DATE
               FROM [dbo].[SpecialCoding] SC
                    INNER JOIN FILES
                    ON SC.[FileID] = FILES.[sysID]
               GROUP BY [Claim-Number],[Question-Number]),

 MAXDATE AS( 
             SELECT [Claim-Number],
                    MAX([MAX_DATE]) AS MAX_DATE
               FROM CTE
              GROUP BY [Claim-Number]),

 FILENUMBER AS(
               SELECT SC.[Claim-Number],
                      SC.[FileID]
                 FROM [dbo].[SpecialCoding] SC
                      INNER JOIN MAXDATE MD
                      ON SC.[Claim-Number] = MD.[Claim-Number]
                         AND SC.[Date-Updated] = MD.[MAX_DATE]
                      INNER JOIN FILES
                      ON SC.[FileID] = FILES.[sysID])

SELECT sub.*, 
       MAXDATE.MAX_DATE AS "Valuation Date",
       FILENUMBER.[FileID] 
  FROM (
        SELECT t2.[Claim-Number],
               MAX(CASE WHEN t2.[Question-Number] = 38 THEN t2.Response ELSE NULL END) AS [Client Name],
               MAX(CASE WHEN t2.[Question-Number] = 2046 THEN t2.Response ELSE NULL END) AS [Record Only],
               MAX(CASE WHEN t2.[Question-Number] = 2558 THEN t2.Response ELSE NULL END) AS [Customer Number],
               MAX(CASE WHEN t2.[Question-Number] = 2691 THEN t2.Response ELSE NULL END) AS [Reporting Source],
               MAX(CASE WHEN t2.[Question-Number] = 2842 THEN t2.Response ELSE NULL END) AS [Estimated Closure Date]
          FROM [dbo].[SpecialCoding] t2
               INNER JOIN CTE 
               ON CTE.[Claim-Number] = t2.[Claim-Number]
                  AND CTE.[Question-Number] = t2.[Question-Number]
                  AND CTE.[MAX_DATE] = t2.[Date-Updated]
         GROUP BY t2.[Claim-Number]) sub
        LEFT JOIN MAXDATE
        ON MAXDATE.[Claim-Number] = sub.[Claim-Number]
        LEFT JOIN FILENUMBER
        ON FILENUMBER.[Claim-Number] = sub.[Claim-Number];
```

**PIVOT SOLUTION**

```
WITH FILES AS (
                SELECT *
                  FROM [dbo].[Files_Dummy]
                 WHERE ImportOutcome = 'Successful'
                  AND FileDescription IN ('SpecialCoding')),

     CTE AS (
             SELECT [Claim-Number],
                    [Question-Number],
                    MAX([Date-Updated]) AS MAX_DATE
               FROM [dbo].[SpecialCoding] SC
                    INNER JOIN FILES
                    ON SC.[FileID] = FILES.[sysID]
               GROUP BY [Claim-Number],[Question-Number]),

 MAXDATE AS( 
             SELECT [Claim-Number],
                    MAX([MAX_DATE]) AS MAX_DATE
               FROM CTE
              GROUP BY [Claim-Number]),

 FILENUMBER AS(
               SELECT SC.[Claim-Number],
                      SC.[FileID]
                 FROM [dbo].[SpecialCoding] SC
                      INNER JOIN MAXDATE MD
                      ON SC.[Claim-Number] = MD.[Claim-Number]
                         AND SC.[Date-Updated] = MD.[MAX_DATE]
                      INNER JOIN FILES
                      ON SC.[FileID] = FILES.[sysID]),

    PT AS (
    SELECT *
      FROM (
            SELECT t2.[Claim-Number],
                   t2.[Question-Number],
                   t2.[Response]
              FROM [dbo].[SpecialCoding] t2
                   INNER JOIN CTE 
                   ON CTE.[Claim-Number] = t2.[Claim-Number]
                      AND CTE.[Question-Number] = t2.[Question-Number]
                      AND CTE.[MAX_DATE] = t2.[Date-Updated]
             ) sub
     PIVOT (
       MAX([Response])
       FOR [Question-Number] IN ([38],[2046],[2558],[2691],[2842])) AS pivot_table)
     SELECT PT.[38] AS "Client Name",
            PT.[2046] AS "Record Only",
            PT.[2558] AS "Customer Number",
            PT.[2691] AS "Reporting Source Indicator Description",
            PT.[2842] AS "Estimated Claim Closure Date", 
            MAXDATE.[MAX_DATE] AS [Valuation Date], 
            FILENUMBER.[FileID]
       FROM PT
            LEFT JOIN MAXDATE
            ON MAXDATE.[Claim-Number] = PT.[Claim-Number]
            LEFT JOIN FILENUMBER
            ON FILENUMBER.[Claim-Number] = PT.[Claim-Number];
```

**PROOF SOLUTIONS WORK**

[image]

Let me walk you through what I am attempting to do.

Your `FILES` common table expression (CTE), I am not sure about since I don't see that data.

The `CTE` CTE, is trying to get this.

[image]

For each combination of `Claim-Number` and `Question`, ONLY pull the one with the max date. This means that the row in red will not show up in the results. I kept `Question-Number` in there just because it is a one-to-one relationship with `Question` and won't affect the combination.

Then,  take your full data set and inner join in to the `CTE` that we created on the field `Claim-Number`, `Question`, `Question-Number`, and `Date-Updated`. The colored rows match up, so the row in the white background will not show up in the results. This means wherever `Claim-Number`, `Question`, `Question-Number`, and `Date-Updated` match exactly on both data sets, keep those rows.

[image]
[image]

So now we have the data set below.
[image]

Now, use `CASE` statements to pivot the data and get the data set below.

[image]

Now in the top, we created `MAXDATE`, which is the data set below. All the rows in red will NOT show up in the result because all we are doing is selecting the `MAX` `Date-Updated` for that `Claim-Number`.

[image]

Join the pivoted data with `MAXDATE` to get the final result.

[image]

Then depending on your logic for `File-ID`, we could bring that in as well. It looks like you are pulling the `File-ID` for the latest `Response`, the one with the most recent `Date-Updated`. Hope that helps clear some of it up! I would honestly change the query a little bit and use `Question-Number` instead of `Question`. It was also challenging because the requirements were changing and you introduced new data a couple times.

Comment: I'll give it a shot and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: I'm having a problem with your recommendation as I only have one table and you reference a table1 and table2.

Comment: Sorry. `table2` is your `table1`. I was trying something else originally and I forgot to change it back. So in `CTE2`, change `table2` to `table1`. Then use `CTE2` to pivot your data on `Event_Number` probably. If your `PIVOT` function doesn't work, let me know. I haven't used it before, so I would have to look into it or try another solution like `CASE` statements.

Comment: I just can't seem to get this to work with your code (errors all over the place). It is most likely due to my inexperience with this code. This was my predecessor's work and so I'm just trying to get it to work. 

Here's what happens when I input your code (broken up into two sections because of the comment limitations):
`CTE AS (
     SELECT [Claim-Number],
            Question,
            MAX([Date-Updated]) [Date-Updated]
       FROM dbo.SpecialCoding t1
      GROUP BY [Claim-Number], Question, [Date-Updated]),`

Comment: No issues there, but next section has issues with Claim-Number, Question and Date-Updated 

`CTE2 AS (     
     SELECT [Claim-Number],
            Question,
            Response,
            [Date-Added],
            [Date-Updated],
            FileID,
            sysID
       FROM dbo.SpecialCoding t2
            INNER JOIN CTE 
            ON CTE.[Claim-Number] = [Claim-Number]
               AND CTE.Question = Question
               AND CTE.[Date-Updated] = [Date-Updated]
    Group by [Claim-Number], Question, [Date-Updated]) `

They all indicate "Ambiguous column name"

Comment: @marmijo what DBMS are you using? You might need to explicitly state the table name before the field. Look at the old code to see the formatting and syntax. Did your predecessor put `[t1].[Claim-Number]' or in some other format? My code might not be perfect, so try executing just the first `SELECT` in `CTE` by itself. Copy form `SELECT` down to `GROUP BY 1,2;` and run that independently to see if it works.

Comment: I see what is happening. You need to specify the tables before the field in the `SELECT` clause because you are pulling in from 2 tables (the same tables in this case) and the field names are identical. In `CTE2` replace your `SELECT` clause with in `SELECT t2.[Claim-Number], t2.Question, t2. Response, t2.[Date-Added], t2.[Date-Updated], t2.FileID, t2.sysID'. Then, in the `INNER JOIN` change it to `CTE.Question = t2.Question AND `CTE.[Date-Updated] = t2.[Date-Updated`. Lastly, change the `GROUP BY` to `t2.[Claim-Number], t2.Question, t2.[Date-Updated]`. Not sure if `GROUP BY` needed in 2nd one

Comment: Nice! That cleaned up all those errors. Now, I have an error at the Pivot function. I'm looking into what is wrong and will keep you updated. Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: Awesome! I can look at the `PIVOT` portion too. Will you only have those same 5 unique questions per `Event-Number`? Will there every be more? If not, will there always be placeholders with `NULL` values if there's no data? What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Yes, just those same 5 questions in this one table and there should always be NULL placeholders I think. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4)

Comment: You could try something like: `SELECT CTE2.[Event-Number], CASE WHEN CTE.Question = 'Client Name' THEN CTE2.Response ELSE NULL AS [Client Name], CASE WHEN CTE.Question = 'Record Only', THEN CTE.Response ELSE NULL...` Continue the `CASE` statement for all 5 question types. Also, you may need to remove FileID from the CTE and CTE2. Which FileID do you need to bring in to the pivot? SQL Server will handle the `PIVOT` function also. I'll post back after I look into it a little.

Comment: Maybe this using `PIVOT`. Take `CTE2` out of the `WITH` clause so you ONLY have CTE in there. Then try the following. `SELECT * FROM (SELECT Event_Number, Question, Response,  Date_Added,    Date_Updated, FileID, sysID FROM table1 t2 INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.Event_Number = t2.Event_Number AND CTE.Question = t2.Question               AND CTE.Date_Updated = t2.Date_Updated) t PIVOT (MAX(RESPONSE) FOR Question IN ([Client Name], [Customer Number], [Record Only], [Reporting Source], [Estimated Closure Date]) AS pvt`.  Reference: http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-pivot/

Comment: Yeah, I've never used the Pivot function either. Actually only been SQL programming for about 4 months now and most of that has been basic select queries.

I tried your CASE solution and had to clean it up a little bit to get rid of most the errors. I still have issues on the following lines, 

`CASE WHEN CTE.Question = 'Client Name' THEN CTE.RESPONSE ELSE NULL AS [Client Name],`

It's telling me that **RESPONSE** is an invalid colulmn name and "Incorrect Syntax" near **AS**.

Comment: SQL is case sensitive for column names and data, so match it exactly to the column header. It should be `CTE.Response`. I also forgot to put `END` in each of the `CASE` statements. Please review my updated solution :).

Comment: Yep, that fixed most of the errors, and adding Response to the CTE select. Now, I'm getting _Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference._ And my CTE looks like this:
`CTE AS
 (
    SELECT [Claim-Number],
           Question, Response,
           MAX([Date-Updated]) AS MAX_DATE --[Date-Updated]
    FROM [dbo].[SpecialCoding] SC
  INNER JOIN FILES
        ON FILES.sysID = SC.FileID
    GROUP BY 1,2 --[Claim-Number], Question, Response, [Date-Updated]
 )`

Comment: You need to `GROUP BY` every column that does not have an aggregate function. So you have 4 columns in your `SELECT` clause. Columns 1 through 3 are not aggregated, so your should `GROUP BY 1,2,3` OR `GROUP BY [Claim-Number], Question, Response`. You can either use the column index or the explicit column name. Looks like you are using a combination and too many columns in your `GROUP BY`. Looks like you changed your `CTE` though and added `Response`. Is that still working for you? The intent is to pull each `[Claim-Number]` and `Question` combination and only use the most recently updated one.

Comment: @marmijo I have added in a detailed explanation that breaks the query down and shows the logic behind each step. I hope that helps you conceptually understand what is happening, which may help you get to your solution faster.

Comment: Everything you just added was super helpful and explains the problem/solution perfectly. Yes, I had to change `CTE` and add `Response` to fix an issue where the `CASE` statements were telling me that the `CTE.Response` was an Invalid column name. I now understand the Group by syntax and have updated it to use the column index. I'm now getting a new error in CTE that reads, _"Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference."_ I'm researching that now.

Comment: Try using my solution, but in those `CASE` statements change it from `CTE.Response` to `t2.Response` and `CTE.Question` to `t2.Question`. I see where the potential issue is. So use my solution (don't add `Response` to the `CTE`) and just make those changes, it should work. I fixed it in my posted solution.

Comment: Yep, that fixed the issues in the case statement and I don't need the response in the CTE. I'm still getting the _"Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference"_ error in the CTE function. I also needed to add a comma after the `CTE AS` function or else I was getting an error on the `MAXDATE` function.

Comment: I see an issue with the `MAXDATE` query in the `WITH` clause. Sorry, I overlooked that. I added in the missing comma you pointed out, and I modified the `MAXDATE` query in the common table expressions. Hopefully this resolves all your issues now :).

Comment: Thanks. I now get an error on the `MAXDATE` function that says, "No Column was specified for column 2 of MAXDATE" and another error on `AND CTE.[Date-Updated] = t2.[Date-Updated]) sub` that says, "Invalid column name '[Date-Updated]'"

Comment: Okay, where it says `sub.*`, I added in `MAXDATE.MAX_DATE` right next to it so it pulls in that date. Then for the other error change `CTE.[Date-Updated]` to `CTE.MAX_DATE`. I adjusted the solution in my post.

Comment: If the `MAXDATE` CTE query gives you issues, try changing it to this. `MAXDATE AS( SELECT Event_Number,
                      MAX([Date_Updated]) AS MAX_DATE
                 FROM [dbo].[SpecialCoding]
                GROUP BY 1)`

Comment: @marmijo I have updated BOTH solutions to include your `FILES` table. Please see my SOLUTION for the proof that it is working based on the data you provided. I am returning ONE row using SQL Server on SQLFiddle. Look at the data set I created for you based on the data you provided and then the solutions I posted. They both are working for me.

Comment: @marmijo I just added 2 additional solutions that use window functions to get the solution. I have posted 4 solutions for you to try now. They are all working for me and returning 1 row of data.

Comment: So close. It works for the record in our sample SpecialCoding table. I looked up another claim-number in our real table and still got multiple results. I'm going to post the code on how to add that data into the SpecialCoding and Files tables as I'm not 100% sure what the difference is with those records and why it would be displaying differently.

Comment: I finally got it! Thanks for all your help. I did add the record rows to the SpecialCoding table in my original post if you want to take a look. For some reason with those rows in there, your code was still giving duplicates. The latest answer I posted is now working for all scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

This is working!

```
WITH
FILES AS
(
SELECT      *
FROM        [dbo].[Files]
WHERE       ImportOutcome = 'Successful'
AND         FileDescription IN ('SpecialCoding')
),

SPCMAX AS -- added max values at top of subquery here or all values except the [claim-number]
(
SELECT      MAX(ValuationDate) AS ValuationDate, MAX(FileID) AS FileID, [Claim-Number], MAX([Client Name]) AS [Client Name],
            MAX([Customer Number]) AS [Customer Number], MAX([Record Only]) AS [Record Only],
            MAX([Reorting Source Indicator Description]) AS [Reorting Source Indicator Description],
            MAX([Estimated Claim Closure Date]) AS [Estimated Claim Closure Date]
FROM        (
            SELECT      MAX(FILES.ValuationDate) OVER (PARTITION BY [Claim-Number], Question /*addedd Question here*/) MAXVAL,
                        FILES.ValuationDate, FileID, [Claim-Number], [Question], [Response]
            FROM        [dbo].[SpecialCoding] SC
            INNER JOIN  FILES
            ON          SC.FileID = FILES.sysID
            WHERE       SC.Response IS NOT NULL -- Added this line here
            ) AS SC
PIVOT
            (
            MAX(Response)
            FOR Question IN ([Client Name], [Customer Number], [Record Only], [Reorting Source Indicator Description], [Estimated Claim Closure Date])
            ) AS PivotTable
WHERE       MAXVAL = ValuationDate
GROUP BY    [Claim-Number] -- added this
)

SELECT      ValuationDate, FileID, [Claim-Number], [Client Name], [Customer Number], [Record Only],
            [Reorting Source Indicator Description], [Estimated Claim Closure Date]
FROM        SPCMAX
```